# Android Button onClick doesnt react

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I know there are a lot of threads which target this question, but no solution could help me out.

I`ve got the following problem:

I want my button on the start screen to use a method in my main activity which puts data from the TextField into a Intent and starts a new Activity with that Intent. The same code did work how it is now on Android Studio, but on Eclipse it doesnt. No errors or anything, LogCat is giving me only this:

> 06-20 14:08:39.003: D/AudioFlinger(1199): mixer(0xb44c0000) throttle end: throttle time(68)

I`ve defined the Button in my acitivity_main.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.jule.bachelorapp.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_standort"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_standort"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_zeit"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_sendData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_sendData"
        android:onClick="viewAdress"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**My MainActivity.java** files looks like this:

```
package com.example.bachelorapp;

import com.example.bachelorapp.R;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void viewAdress(View view){
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_standort);
        String adresse = editText.getText().toString();
        Uri mapIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+ Uri.encode(adresse));
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mapIntentUri);
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        if(mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
            startActivity(mapIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

The Acitivty I want to open after the button press is my MapActivity.java:

```
package com.example.bachelorapp;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        LatLng adress = new LatLng(48.362206, 10.908704);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(adress)
                .title("Zuhause"));
    }
}
```

Does anyone know, why the button with the android:onClick doesnt react ?

I hope you can help me out,

Greetings
Jule

Comment: May be because of this mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps"); you dont need to setPackage for your own activity

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the Activity the text from your EditText, you would do something like this.

```
public void viewAdress(View view) { 
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(this, MapActivity.class);
    //Place string as putExtra or place inside a bundle
    mapIntent.putExtra("editTextString", editText.getText().toString());
    startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

Comment: In this tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#intent-anforderungen

the intent structure for Google Maps are given and I think my code covers that. It`s just strange, that the same code worked in Android Studio but not in Eclipse

Comment: The tutorial you linked says 

`"The Google Maps app for Android exposes several intents that you can use to launch Google Maps in display, search, navigation, or Street View modes. If you want to embed a map in your app, please refer to the Google Maps Android API Getting Started Guide."` 

and  from the code you linked it would appear you're using the API and not trying to launch the actual maps app? Seems as you have a MapsActivity you want to open?

Comment: Uh, don`t I launch the actual maps app with my code ? I thought creating an Intent with the given data and starting the MapActivity like in the tutorial I linked would start the app with the Intent

Answer (score 0):

This might help you with some of the constructs you need,
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/intent/launch_the_map_application/

Answer (score 0):

You should set your activity package name instead of `mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")` This call google maps which you do not have installed on your device or emulator.

Comment: Since I want to use Google Maps in the MapActivity, I should let that package as it is, right ?

Comment: I installed the Google API, Google Play Services etc in Eclipse. Does it apply on my AVD's too or do I need to install it on them seperatly ? (And if yes, how)

Comment: I am using Genymotion. Maps does not work if are not installed on Genymotion. I guess the same is for standard AVD.

Comment: You can always test your app on your device instead of AVD.

Comment: I have no USB cabel to connect my device with my laptop.. should buy one i guess, would be more convenient :)

Comment: I have just upgraded AS to version 2.1.2. I started AVD emulator of Nexus 5X API 23 and Maps are installed there. I had to login for Google Account and works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip">
</Button>
```

you have to call the button -->findViewById()

```
   Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried it with the listener too but it didnt work. I have to get Google Maps on the emulator run and see if my code works then